# Azure AD B2C Password reset is not working

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

After resetting the user password, b2c login page is not redirecting to the change password screen. It was working earlier.

Steps to reproduce:

reset the user's password via azure portal
login using the temporary password
login screen showing "Your password has expired." error message instead of redirecting to "Update expired password page"

[image: Login screen]

Answer (score 0):

We use [**password reset flow**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow) to reset password of Azure B2C user, but not click reset password button on user profile. Please refer to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54802805/13308381) to learn more about it.

And the error "Your password has expired." is expected.

> When you reset the password using admin account from Azure AD Portal,
> a temporary password is generated which is marked as expired and
> requires the user to provide a new password. Since, in B2C there is a
> different mechanism for resetting password (i.e. by using Password
> Reset User flows/Custom Policies), users don't get the option to reset
> the password and only get `The password has expired.` message. In B2C,
> administrator accounts cannot be used to reset password of consumer
> accounts.

You may consider using one of the below custom policies:

1. Azure AD B2C: [Force password reset first logon](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-password-reset-first-logon)
2. Azure AD B2C: [Force password after 90 days](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/force-password-reset-after-90-days)