# Azure b2c cannot enable sspr

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c

We are using signup/signin builtin user flow and want to combine the "forgot password" part into this flow though sspr https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-reset-policy?pivots=b2c-user-flow#self-service-password-reset-recommended

However, the sspr bottun unable to click in user flow property and show a line at the bottom "sspr currently unavailable to support combind local account", am I using the wrong account or APIM needs to do some conf?

I have searched a while and there is no similar case. Has anyone encountered the same problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if below are the causes:

> **Note :** In a sign-up and sign-in journey, a user can reset their own
> password by using the Forgot your password link. This ability to
> reset passwords only apply to **local accounts** in Azure Active Directory
> B2C (Azure AD B2C)  i.e; you can only reset your password if you
> signed up using an email address or a username with a password  for
> sign-in .

- In case of azure ad, users of SSPR requires one of the following [licenses](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/concept-sspr-licensing#compare-editions-and-features): Azure AD
  Premium P1 or P2, Microsoft 365 Business, or Office 365. If you have
  a hybrid environment, you also need password writeback into your
  on-premises AD. In this case, you’ll need Azure AD Premium P1 or P2
  or Microsoft 365 Business.
- You may not be able to see password reset menu option if you don't have an Azure
  AD license assigned to the administrator performing the operation.

Please check out below references:

1. [Troubleshoot self-service password reset - Azure Active Directory | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/troubleshoot-sspr)
2. [Frequently asked questions (FAQ) for Azure Active Directory B2C | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/faq?tabs=app-reg-ga#what-are-local-accounts-in-azure-ad-b2c--how-are-they-different-from-work-or-school-accounts-in-azure-ad-)
3. [Azure AD B2C Password Reset - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54787974/azure-ad-b2c-password-reset)

Comment: Thanks your response and the issue is fixed by Identity provider changed to email or phone, it can't use the sspr functions if selected the email and phone in Identity provder.