# Azure AD Log Analytics requires resource provider microsoft.insights

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Using Azure Portal, select my AD B2C, choose Active Directory, choose Monitoring => Logs. (I think everything is configured correctly, I'm seeing signins and audits in my storage account)

Query page shows error "To run this query, register resource provider 'Microsoft.Insights' for this subscription."

I have checked my subscriptions resource providers page and Microsoft.Insights is registered. I have tried to re-register it but the error remains.

I don't have Azure support, so I'm asking here if anyone has any insights?

Comment: Fairly certain you need to enable it on B2C tenant\subscription, not on your own tenant\subscription (because B2C is a different tenant)

Comment: Thanks - I checked both the master tenant/subscription and the B2C tenant/subscription and both have microsoft.insights registered in the Resource Providers list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to perform the query from the log analytics blade in the master subscription not from the tenant.

Answer (score 0):

You should not use the features of the subscription in your B2C tenant, even you can use some of them, B2C tenant is not designed for these features, it will result in many issues.

For more details, see - [What's the difference between Azure AD B2C tenant and normal Azure AD tenant?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628730/whats-the-difference-between-azure-ad-b2c-tenant-and-normal-azure-ad-tenant)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I know the OP mentioned that he tried re-registering the *microsoft.insights* provider, but I wanted to leave this answer here for anybody that comes along and has not yet tried this approach.

So, in my case, I just needed to re-register the *microsoft.insights* provider on the affected subscription.

The guide from Microsoft for registering resource providers can be found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/troubleshooting/error-register-resource-provider?tabs=azure-portal).

Short summary of the steps:

- go to the subscriptions list
- select the one affected
- in the left side menu, under *Settings*, select *Resource providers*
- in the list that opens navigate to *microsoft.insights*, select it and press *Re-register* option in the top menu