# What are the benefits of using Azure AD B2C tenant now that External Identities are now available in regular Azure AD?

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-ad-b2c

Now that I can let users sign up for a regular Azure AD tenant with Google, Facebook, etc accounts, what advantages does Azure AD B2C still offer?  I know one big disadvantage they have is not offering application roles.

Answer (score 1):

To understand why we need to use Azure B2C, I think you need to learn the differences between AAD and AAD B2C.

We can say AAD is mainly for employee and B2C is mainly for customer.

Although we can add guests into regular Azure AD, we can't use an AAD tenant for millions of customers.

Separating the management of customers and employees is an important role of B2C.

There are several other reasons why we use B2C. For details, you can refer to this [good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51628730/whats-the-difference-between-azure-ad-b2c-tenant-and-normal-azure-ad-tenant?answertab=votes#tab-top).